# jQuery ajax call - What format should jim script response be?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this has been answered before but I search the net and this site and I couldn't find the answer...

I have a javascript function that calls a jim script to perform various SQLite DB queries.

This is the js function:

```
insertRecord: function(uri, name, img, added) 
{
    $.post('http://localhost/portal/jim/script.jim', { 'action': 'insert', 'uri': uri, 'name': name, 'img': img, 'added': added });
}
```

This is the code for the insert in script.jim:

```
insert {
    $db query {
        insert into favourites(uri, name, img, added) values('%s','%s','%s', '%s')
    } $uri $name $img $added
}
```

It all works fine except the timings sometimes are out when I insert and then the jQuery to append the html from reading the DB returns after the html has been applied.

Anyway, I was then thinking I would use $.ajax but I'm not sure how to change the script.jim to return a valid formatted response for $.ajax.

What would need to be returned to let jQuery know that the POST or GET was success: complete: error: done: etc.?

I got the jim script off a friend so I am not sure of that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
mcquaim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to return anything. Just ensure that the response code for your jim script is 200. If it is then your success handler gets called, else your error handler gets called.

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url:"http://localhost/portal/jim/script.jim",
data: { 'action': 'insert', 'uri': uri, 'name': name, 'img': img, 'added': added },
  success: function(){
   // success handler
},
error : function(){
   // error handler
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not sure what you mean by checking the response code for the jim script is 200. Where would I need to check for this code?